# Custom System.Text JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset> not getting invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, json.net, system.text.json

I am creating a custom JsonConverterto parse datetimeoffset, to fix utc issue with offset. I am following [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace SystemTextJsonSamples
{
    public class DateTimeOffsetJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset>
    {
        public override DateTimeOffset Read(
            ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type typeToConvert,
            JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
                DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(reader.GetString()!,
                    "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            DateTimeOffset dateTimeValue,
            JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
                writer.WriteStringValue(dateTimeValue.ToString(
                    "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

I have registered the converter in the startup like so

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase));
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeOffsetConverter());
            })
```

and here is my model

```
 [Serializable()]
public class Travel
{
   
    public DateTimeOffset TravelTime { get; set; }

}
```

When i make call to my api, my custom converter for datetimeoffset is not getting called. Please note that i also have a customdate converter which is working as expected.

Why is my offsetdatetime converter not getting invoked when i serialize/deserialize.
I am using .Net core 6

Comment: How are you doing the json serialization?

Answer (score 3):

It's not enough to define a `JsonConverter`, you also have to apply it to the property, like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeOffsetJsonConverter))]
public DateTimeOffset TravelTime { get; set; }
```

Then it will be used for serialization and deserialization.

The reason for this (like why can't it pick up the type?) is that you can have several converters defined for the **same type** and apply them to the properties that need them. Now you can actually make different 'string to string' converters (for example).

Comment: But i have only one datetimeoffset converter

Comment: Also i tried removing the datetime converter from the list of registered converters

Comment: It doesn't matter that you only have one. You _could_ have several and therefore it's been coded so that it is expected of you to use the annotation.

Comment: builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeOffsetConverter());
});   

[HttpPost]
public MyClass Post(MyClass myClass)
{
 return myClass;
}

public class MyClass
{
 public DateTime FirstDate { get; set; }

 public DateTimeOffset LastDate { get; set; }
}

Tried it in a simple web api, both the converters are invoked without having to add an attribute

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it should be `DateTimeOffsetJsonConverter` instead of `DateTimeOffsetConverter`, change your code to:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase));
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
  //options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeOffsetConverter());
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeOffsetJsonConverter());

});
```

Then, be sure you post the data with **content type `application/json`**. For example:

[image]

Besides, you can also add `[FromBody]` to specify the source because it binds the form data by default if you use asp.net core MVC project:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index([FromBody]Travel model)
{
    //do your stuff...
}
```